# Call to undefined function sccp_get_model_data()

Tags: php, mysql, undefined-function

Hoping someone can help me with a **Call to undefined function** error I am getting in the following code:

```
$query = \FreePBX::Database()->query('SELECT model, dns, buttons, loadimage
            FROM sccpdevmodel
            WHERE dns > 0
            ORDER BY model');

$res = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($res as $row) { 
    $modelData['model'][] = $row[0];
    $modelData['dns'][] = $row[1];
    $modelData['buttons'][] = $row[2];
    $modelData['loadimage'][] = $row[3];
}
return $modelData;
```

This first part seems to be ok then I get the error `$modelData = sccp_get_model_data();` in this line.

```
<?php
    $modelData = sccp_get_model_data();
    $numModels = count($modelData['model']);
    $addonData = sccp_get_addon_data();
    $numAddons = count($addonData['model']);

?>
```

Any advice?

Here is a link to the source file if anyone can help please?
https://github.com/Cynjut/SCCP_Manager/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using an include or require statement to load your functions. I found what seems to be the full code base for this on [github](https://github.com/Cynjut/SCCP_Manager/blob/6805563ceb682eabd358166c75b55df3bbbbb463/page.sccp_devices.php) and didn't see where it loads in the functions you use.
Not sure if you want them conditionally loaded, but if not, you can `include 'functions.inc.php';` at the top of the file that needs to use them.

Comment: Ok, so I added the `include 'functions.ini.php` but I now get **Cannot redeclare sccp_reset_phone() (previously declared in /var/www/html/admin/modules/sccp_manager/functions.inc.php:9)**

    `     function sccp_reset_phone($name) {
    global $astman; 
 
    $astman->Command("sccp reset ".$name);
 
}
 
function sccp_get_asterisk_version() { `

Comment: make sure you check your spelling: functions.ini.php != functions.inc.php

Comment: Sorry my mistake it was `include functions.inc.php` I added and get the error **Cannot redeclare sccp_reset_phone() (previously declared in /var/www/html/admin/modules/sccp_manager/functions.inc.php:9)** .  Maybe it does have to have be conditional load or something but I have _no_ idea how to do that?  Any other suggestions?